# Android - how to load images into scrollview that has visible on screen?

Tags: android, scrollview, universal-image-loader

I am using scrollview to show images (Property images) in nxn matrix but it takes me more time. To load images i am using universal image loader

```
        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .threadPoolSize(1)
        .discCacheExtraOptions(225,145, CompressFormat.PNG, 100,null)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .build();
         imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
         imageLoader.init(config);
         options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();
```

And i am using this as

```
imageLoader.displayImage(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SaintGobain/Images/"+projectDetail.get(dbHelper.thumb_image_path), thumb, options);
```

I have more images to display like 10 columns and 15 to 20 images in each column. so i want the images which are visible that one has to load first on scroll of view the remaining has to load .
Plz guide me how to customize the universal image loader ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to use **androidquery** framework to load images asynchronously.

Go through this Link

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Jar and source code both are available.